# Show valid email address on the angular prompt

Tags: html, typescript, angular8

I have created a temporary password email which any user can get once they click on the forgot password feature. After getting the temp pass they will see a prompt asking them to enter that temp pass. I want to show the same valid email address they have used or associated with the account they have on the angular prompt or pop-up text box. Currently I have created a prompt where I am not able to show the email, since I have not used it before.

My concern is how can I trigger the email address so that it will be visible on that pop-up prompt?

email address as an example: ***abcd@yahoo.com***

I know how to use the **<a>** tag using **href=""** for the backend to share hyperlinks, but I'm not familiar how to show or how to trigger any email link on an angular prompt.

Below codes are what I have for the .html and the .ts files.

**temporary.component.ts**

```
tempPasswordTextLbl: "We have sent a temp pass to the abcd@yahoo.com email you provided. Please enter it below.",
```

**temporary.component.html**

```
<p style="margin: 30px; text-align: justify; font-size:15px;">{{header.oneTimePasswordMessageLbl?header.oneTimePasswordMessageLbl:headerText.oneTimePasswordMessageLbl}}</p>
```

Below is the image of the prompt and the email should show up as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood it, first you need to check if the email is valid and only then show the popup informing that the code was sent to the email previously informed.

For this you need to use FormBuilder, FormGroup and Validators

**html**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <h3>Angular Form Validation</h3>
        <form [formGroup]="myregisterForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email: {{ myEmail }}</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              [(ngModel)]="myEmail"
              formControlName="email"
              class="form-control"
              [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.email.errors }"
            />
            <div *ngIf="submitted && f.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
              <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.email">
                Email must be a valid email address
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  myregisterForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  myEmail = ''; // need to use text interpolation in html

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myregisterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: [
        '',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.email,
          Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$'),
        ],
      ],
    });
  }

  // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
  get f() {
    return this.myregisterForm.controls;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.myregisterForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    alert(
      'We have sent the temp pass to: ' + this.myEmail + ' email you provided'
    );
  }
}
```

See working example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-email-validation-8emwpn?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Actually, I need to know how to show the email address on prompt. If you take a look at my screenshot, I want to show the email address which is in blue color. I don't want to create the email validator pop-up or anything. Imagine you have entered your email address to receive the temp pass through your email, now that you have to enter the temp pass on the prompt, it will show your email on that same prompt as well. I want to know how can I do that?

Comment: If you see my example link the e-mail is show using (ngModel)  [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-email-validation-8emwpn?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: oh yeah :) I somehow missed alert part. Thanks a lot.